# Can't submit build to iTunes Connect. Using Xcode 7.3.1. Error about beta

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I am trying to submit a build to iTunes Connect using Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1012), but I'm getting an error if I use the "Generic iOS Device" to build the archive. I can submit if I plug in an iOS 9 or less device.

The error is "Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later..."

I did have Xcode 8 installed so I tried completely removing Xcode 8 and 7 from my machine by deleting the apps from Applications and removing the Developer & Xcode folders from /Library and ~/Library. I even removed any preference plist files I could find.

I had not even opened the project with Xcode 8.

This is a pain because Fastlane uses the "Generic iOS Device" for its builds so I have to manually submit with Xcode.

I'm using OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Anyone else experiencing this or have any suggestions? This problem seems to come up from time to time judging by a google search for this issue, with posts here and on the Apple Developer forums, but there are never any definitive solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem of iTunes Connect. They may not update the latest version number of 10.11.6 in iTunes Connect. Try again now, it should be working fine.